# How can I automatically generate and consistently cross-reference equation and subequation numbers in Microsoft Word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, equations, numbering

*I write this question as Q&A after picking together
information from different sources. For some issues I haven't found solutions, see [answer part](https://superuser.com/a/1575653/191663).*

---

I want to create equations with numbering on the same line.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
sed  diam  nonumy  eirmod   tempor  invidunt  ut  labore

                         x + y
         ∑    x * y =    -----                       (1)
          n              x - y

et  dolore magna  aliquyam erat,  sed diam  voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
                                                           |Unnumbered  |
                   x = ...                                 |intermediate|
                   y = ...                                 |equation    |

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
sed  diam  nonumy  eirmod   tempor  invidunt  ut  labore

                        x = f(a,b)                  (2a)
                        y = g(c,d)                  (2b)
                        n = z(x,y)                  (2c)

et ea rebum. Stet clita  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
sanctus  est Lorem  ipsum  dolor sit  amet, see
Eqs. (1,2b,2c).
```

How can I produce such equations, such that equation numbers
can be made consistent with "Update fields"
(<kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>) and cross-reference the
equations consitently, i.e. such that updating the numbering
also updates the references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Wording of UI elements may deviate slightly, due to my
Version being in German. I googled, what the terms should be
in English.).

```
Contents
------
1. Adding a “display” style equation
2. Inserting an equation number field
3. Referencing auto-numbered equations
4. Subequation numbering
5. Open Issues
```

## 1. Adding a “display” style equation

---

Use “Insert→Equation→New Equation” for creating a new
equation. For making it a display-style equation instead of
an inline equation, simply put it on a new line. Such
equations should differ in several way, by

1. Being centered, and
2. Having superscripts and subscripts of operators like
   the ∑ and ∫ placed above and below instead of to the
   side of the operator.

as would be the case with the LaTeX constructs

```
\begin{equation} .. \end{equation}
$$ .. $$
\[ .. \]
```

**If it behaves differently.** This might be disable in a
given document, especially when working with collaborators
or third-party templates.

The setting can be found by placing the cursor inside an
equation or creating a new equation through the ribbon
“Insert→Equation→NewEquation” and then accessing the
Equation options through the ribbon “EquationTools/Design”,
where the options are hidden in the <kbd>↘</kbd> button of
the "Tools" section at the left of the ribbon.

In the options the section "Display math" these settings are
controlled. In doubt just use the "defaults" button at the
bottom.

Additionally, this dialog allows customizing
display-math formatting consistently.

## 2. Inserting an equation number field

---

Word 2016 has support for *manual* equation numbering, similar
to using the `\tag` command in LaTeX. For instance typing
`x=1#(23)<Enter>` will produce

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
sed  diam  nonumy  eirmod   tempor  invidunt  ut  labore

                          x = 1                     (23)

et  dolore magna  aliquyam erat,  sed diam  voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores.
```

An automatic number can be generated using “References →
Insert Caption” (ger. “Verweise → Beschriftung einfügen”),
but this is grayed out inside equations. Instead,

1. Create the equation number field outside an equation
   with “References → Insert Caption”. Select the type
   “Equation” (if it doesn't exist yet or has been deleted
   use the “New Label” button to create it and select the
   option “Exclude label from caption”.

   This creates an auto-numbered field. It also sets the
   paragraph style to “Caption”; Change it back to “Text
   Body” or “Standard” in the “Home” ribbon.
2. Cut the field (<kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd>) and use it as
   equation number using the `#(number)<Enter>` pattern,
   but instead of `<number>` paste the field with
   <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>.

For future convenience, it is helpful to store the equation
number as reuseable text snippet (ger. "Schnellbausteine")
in the “Insert” ribbon, or to store a numbered equation as
template in the “Insert → Equation” interface. You can also
just copy-paste previous equations; The numbers will be the
same only until updating the fields.

## 3. Referencing auto-numbered equations

---

*I found a common recommendation to just copy/paste the
generated equation numbers.* **This is wrong.** *Doing so
will break the reference, when updating the numbering,
because it doesn't insert a reference to the equation
number, but a new auto-numbered field, that just hasn't been
updated yet.*

Normally, you'd insert cross-references with “Insert → Cross
Reference”. However, this interface considers everything
left of the number as part of the category label, and Word
2016 offers no choice to insert only the number, so using
this directly will insert the whole equation instead of the
numberical reference.

Instead, we need to create a named bookmark (ger.
“Textmarke”) by selecting the equation number field – only
the number, without surrounding braces – and using “Insert →
Bookmark”.

We can then insert a self-updating and hyperlinked copy of the
marked text, i.e. the equation number, using “Insert → Cross
Reference” using the reference type “Bookmark” using the
“Bookmark content” (ger. “Textmarkeninhalt”) option for the
reference contents.

Surrounding naming like "Eq. (...)" has to be done by hand.
Here it comes in handy to use a “protected space” inserted
with <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Space</kbd> to prevent unwanted line
breaking like

```
yada   yada   yada   yada   See   Eq.
(1) and yada yada yada yada yada yada
```

LaTeX equivalents would be `Eq.\,(\ref{NAME})` or
`Eq.~(\ref{NAME})`. I'm not sure if there is a
straight-forward way of inserting a thin protected space
(`\,`) in Word.

## 4. Subequation numbering

---

This doesn't seem to be directly supported, but it can be
worked around using the features already used.

1. Insert an auto-numbered equation as before. Manually
   add `a` after the number field.
2. In subsequent lines, do *not* add the auto-numbered
   equation and do *not* copy paste the field; These would
   result in new, differing equation numbers being
   assigned upon <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>.

   Instead, create a bookmark for field-part of the first
   equation number and use a cross-reference to repeat the
   number. Add `b`, `c`, `d` etc. manually. (Automatic
   creation of the letters could be possible, but since
   this numbering is very local it is not work the
   effort.)

   The result will be something like

   ```
   sed  diam  nonumy  eirmod   tempor  invidunt  ut  labore

                           x = f(a,b)                  (2a)
                           y = g(c,d)                  (2b)
                           n = z(x,y)                  (2c)

   et ea rebum. Stet clita  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
   ```

   where the `2` in `(2a)` is an auto-numbered field, the
   `2` in `(2b)` and `(2c)` is a reference to a bookmark
   to this field, and `a`,`b`,`c` are manually added letters.
3. For referencing the whole equation, use the bookmark
   created for the number in (2). For referencing
   subequations, create new bookmarks, that include number
   and letter of the subequation.

## 5. Open Issues

---

In LaTeX, it is trivial to create multi-line equations that
are both aligned at some symbol and have numbers usable for
cross-references with the `align` environment, with

```
\begin{align}
  x &= hello + world \\
  y &= foo + bar
\end{align}
```

Resulting in

```
sed  diam nonumy  eirmod  tempor invidunt  ut labore  et
dolore magna aliquyam erat,

                   x = hello + world                (42)
                   y = foo + bar                    (43)

sed diam voluptua.  At vero eos et accusam  et justo duo
dolores et ea  rebum. Stet clita kasd  gubergren, no sea
```

For unnumbered equations, word has an alignment feature,
that can either be used by selecting a symbol for alignment
and setting it as alignment element through the context
menu, or by typing LaTeX-style input where `&=` will be
converted to an aligning `=`.

However, inserting a number with the `#()` method breaks all
such alignment.

Comment: i just found this amazing answer! thank you for the detailed explanation. as great as this is, I am dumbstruck at how completely backwards equation numbering is done to this day in ms office after all this time! jumping through som many hoops just to achieve what latex achieves with a simple `\label{}` it is trully an amazing feat!

Comment: @lucian Sadly, equations are a rather niche topic by the standards of office word processors. All other office suits I know do even worse. And WYSIWYG focus often leads to bad practices or outright broken documents; The wide use of MS Office in particular additionally leads to plenty of outright *wrong* how-tos on the internet.